# chromecast custom receiver - playlist advances media without "onLoad" animation

Tags: javascript, git, chromecast

Using the examples on git, i switched from a playlist implemented on the "sender" side to a replica of the sample [playlist](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideosPlaylist-chrome/blob/master/player_playlist_receiver.html). (receiver-side playlist)

Works fine but, there is no "onLoad" animation on the TV set. Normally, the load animation will fire on receipt of a  LOAD message from the sender and you see very brief animation at bottom of TV the progressBar along with media.title, description, studio, and the thumbnail.

What i want ... when the playlist receiver adavances to the next playlist.item it should fire the event that calls the loading animation.

I dont see where in "libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js" this might be due to the minify/uglify nature of that source code.

What can i do at line #95 of the playlist_receiver to include a loading animation on the TV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cast SDK now supports queueing, both on the sender and receiver sides so please review the new APIs that are added for this purpose, check out the [CastVideos-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) and the [reference receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample) and also the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/autoplay) to see if your question is answered; if not, please come back here and let us know what is missing to get you going.